# Sorting with non transitive comparator

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting

```
struct A { int a, b, c; };
```

Here I need to sort instances of A, with a logic like

```
if (lhs.a == rhs.a) { return lhs.b < rhs.b; }
else { return lhs.c < rhs.c; }
```

Is bubble sort the only alternative? I know `std::sort` fails.

**Edit:**

`std::sort` fails in the sense that the comparing logic isn't transitive.

If we have `k1`, `k2`, `k3`; with say `k1 < k2` because of `k1.a!=k2.a && k1.c < k2.c;` and `k2 < k3` because of `k2.a != k3.a && k2.c < k3.c;` this doesn't imply `k1 < k3` as here `k1.a == k3.a` but we don't know if `k1.b < k2.b`

This is *not* a duplicate. Sorting with custom objects is trivial I know, the question pertains to transitive comparator.

```
k1: a=0, b=3, c=5;
k2: a=1, b=4, c=6; 
k3: a=0, b=2, c=7;
```

Here:

```
k1 < k2 (as k1.a != k2.a so check c: k1.c < k2.c)
k2 < k3 (as k2.a != k3.a so check c: k2.c < k3.c)
k1 < k3 ? (k1.a == k3.a so check b: k1.b > k3.b)
```

so `k1 < k2 && k2 < k3` doesn't imply `k1 <k3`

Comment: It doesn't fail. You have to declare a compare function. In that compare function write what you have written return the boolean value. Call `std::sort` as `sort(start_iterator, end_iterator, compare_function_name)`.

Comment: _"I know std::sort fails"_ o_O :| ?

Comment: *How* does `std::sort` fail? Can you please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and show us?

Comment: I've closed this for now, but will reopen if the OP will edit the question to show that it's about something else

Comment: If it's not transitive, it's not sorting. See [this](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19013/is-transitivity-required-for-a-sorting-algorithm)

Comment: Also check this: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare So basically yes, `std::sort` requires the comparator to be transitive among other things

Comment: If it's not transitive, the final order won't be unique. So what order will you expect?

Comment: If it's not transitive, then in general the input can contain cycles, and if the input contains cycles then **every possible order violates some comparison result**.  So even if a sorting algorithm terminates without crashing (it may crash; it may loop forever), the final result can't really be called "sorted".